# Oracle sql not exists deletes all my records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables

```
product
product_id
parent_product_id

product_details
product_id
percent
```

and parent tables:

```
parent_product
parent_product_id
description_1

parent_product_details
parent_product_id
percent
```

What I need is logic to delete from product_detail where not exists(..the data from parent_product_detail)

and then

insert into product_detail where not exists (data from parent_product_details)

When I execute this

```
delete from product_details pd
where not exists
  (select ppd.*
    from parent_product pp,
         parent_product pd,
         product p,
         parent_product_details ppd,
         ,product_details pd
         where pp.parent_product_id = '172' 
         and pd.parent_product_id = ppd.parent_product_id   
         and ppd.parent_product_id = pp.parent_product_id
         and pd.product_id = p.product_id -- this filter 
  )
  /

rollback
/

1040 rows deleted 

Roll Back Completed
```

The problem I have is that product doesn't have any product details. So when the the subquery is selected / execute it shows only one result

```
select ppd.*
        from parent_product pp,
             parent_product pd,
             product p,
             parent_product_details ppd,
             --,product_details pd
             where pp.parent_product_id = '172' 
             and pd.parent_product_id = ppd.parent_product_id   
             and ppd.parent_product_id = pp.parent_product_id
             --and pd.product_id = p.product_id -- this filter
```

How do I go about deleting from product_details the records no longer present in the parent_product_details and then add new ones with insert into not exists logic?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a *correlated subquery*.  You also need to fix your syntax to use proper `JOIN` syntax, not the archaic commas-in-the-from-clause thing:

```
delete from product_details pd
where not exists (select 1
                  from parent_product pp join
                       parent_product_details ppd
                       on ppd.parent_product_id = pp.parent_product_id join
                       parent_product mc
                       on mc.parent_product_id = ppd.component_parent_product_id
                       product p
                       on p.parent_product_id = pp.parent_product_id
                  where pp.parent_product_id = '172' and
                        pd.product_id = p.product_id -- this filter 
                 );
```

Comment: I think the problem is that product does not contain any product_details so it deletes so many rows